# setState not updating even after callback. Calling this.state.loop in a loop does not render updated state

Tags: reactjs, callback, react-redux, state, setstate

Overhere I'm using await and a callback to setstate to my store_result state and made it an await call. So that when I call the function depends on it it is already updated. I read many relevant posts and added callbacks but I just can't seem to understand why this is not working.

```
await this.setState({ store_result: this.state.store_result}, function () {
      console.log(this.state.store_result);
    });


    this.CalculateDetails();
```

When I console.log(store_results) with setState , the state is updated but handleDetails still recieves an empty store_result.

```
handleSelect = async address => {
    let results = await  geocodeByAddress(address)
    let latLng = await getLatLng(results[0]);
    this.state.coordsPair.push(latLng);

    let codeResults = await geocodeByAddress(address)

    console.log(this.state.coordsPair)
    const {coordsPair} = this.state;
    const {store_result}= this.state;

    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.createElement('div'));
    this.googlePlaces = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    var request = {
      location: coordsPair[0],
      radius: '5000',
      type: ['restaurant','point_of_interest']
    };

    
    this.googlePlaces.nearbySearch(request, callback);

    function callback(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        console.log(results.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          store_result.push(results[i].place_id)
        }
      }
    }

    await this.setState({ store_result: this.state.store_result}, function () {
      console.log(this.state.store_result);
    });


    this.CalculateDetails();

  };
```

This is the function called after the call back sets state.

```
CalculateDetails(){
 
  console.log("details");

    const {store_result}= this.state; 
    const {details} = this.state;
    var wait;
    for(var i = 0; i < store_result.length; i++) {
      //console.log("4");
      let map = new google.maps.Map(document.createElement('div'));
      this.googlePlaces = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

      var request2 = {
        placeId: store_result[i],
        fields: ['name', 'rating', 'formatted_phone_number', 'geometry','website','opening_hours','review','price_level']
      };
      //console.log("1");
  
      this.googlePlaces.getDetails(request2, callback2);

      function callback2(place, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          details.push(place);
  
        }
    }
   
  }

 this.setState({ details: this.state.details}, function () {
      console.log(this.details);
    });
}
```

**CURRENT UPDATE**
I have updated my handleSelect function to

```
 handleSelect = async (address) => {
    let results = await geocodeByAddress(address);
    let latLng = await getLatLng(results[0]);
    this.state.coordsPair.push(latLng);
  
    let codeResults = await geocodeByAddress(address);
  
    console.log(this.state.coordsPair);
    const { coordsPair } = this.state;
    const { store_result } = this.state;
    const store_result_updated = [...store_result]; //<----here
  
    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.createElement("div"));
    this.googlePlaces = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  
    var request = {
      location: coordsPair[0],
      radius: "5000",
      type: ["restaurant", "point_of_interest"],
    };
  
    this.googlePlaces.nearbySearch(request, callback);
  
    function callback(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        console.log(results.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          store_result_updated.push(results[i].place_id);//<----here
        }
      }
    }
  
    this.setState({ store_result: store_result_updated }, function () {
      //<----here
      console.log(this.state.store_result);
      this.calculateDetails();

    });
  
  };
```

This is the current update on calculateDetails(). The odd thing is check1 prints one the length as 0 but check2 doesn't even print out the length inside the for loop.

```
calculateDetails(){
 
  console.log("details");

    const {store_result}= this.state; 
    const {details} = this.state;
  
    const details_updated = [...details]; //<----here

    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.createElement('div'));
    this.googlePlaces = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    console.log(store_result.length);//-> check1

    for(var i = 0; i < store_result.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.state.store_result.length); //check2
      

      var request2 = {
        placeId: store_result[i],
        fields: ['name', 'rating', 'formatted_phone_number', 'geometry','website','opening_hours','review','price_level']
      };
      
      this.googlePlaces.getDetails(request2, callback2);

      function callback2(place, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          details_updated.push(place);
  
        }

        
    }

    this.setState({ details: details_updated}, function () {
      console.log(this.state.details);
   });
   
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't `await` `setState` as it's not an async function. The callback given as the second argument to `setState` is called after the state is set. This is where you be calling `CalculateDetails` (should should be named `calculateDetails`).

Comment: setState is async in nature. But in the above question, it was unnecessary.

Comment: @Mohit it's asynchronous in nature, because of the React lifecycle, which is why it takes a callback to be called after the state update. Regardless, you can't `await` it because it's not marked as an `async` method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: I did what you said. Even then ```CalculateDetails``` returns an empty array. When I try to console.log its length, it doesn't even print that to the console.

Answer (score 0):

You are mutatiing the state directly(in for-loop) which will not cause any re-render.

And, with this, `this.setState({ store_result: this.state.store_result}` you are storing same value from state which is wrong.

Also, awaiting for setState is totally unnecessary.

**Refactored Code**

```js
handleSelect = async (address) => {
  let results = await geocodeByAddress(address);
  let latLng = await getLatLng(results[0]);
  this.state.coordsPair.push(latLng);

  let codeResults = await geocodeByAddress(address);

  console.log(this.state.coordsPair);
  const { coordsPair } = this.state;
  const { store_result } = this.state;
  const store_result_updated = [...store_result]; //<----here

  let map = new google.maps.Map(document.createElement("div"));
  this.googlePlaces = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  var request = {
    location: coordsPair[0],
    radius: "5000",
    type: ["restaurant", "point_of_interest"],
  };

  this.googlePlaces.nearbySearch(request, callback);

  function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      console.log(results.length);
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        store_result_updated.push(results[i].place_id);//<----here
      }
    }
  }

  this.setState({ store_result: store_result_updated }, function () {
    //<----here
    console.log(this.state.store_result);
  });

  this.CalculateDetails();
};
```

Comment: this.calculateDetails() still return an empty array though.    I did the same thing for calculateDetails() const details_updated = [...details], and set the state according however all I console.log is an empty array. When I try to debug it and console.log the length of store_result , it doesn't print it to the console.